# Stop a while loop if values are the same - Java

Tags: java, while-loop

Basically, I have this while loop that retrieves the co-ordinates of a button pressed (which is a chess piece) and goes through the loop to see if a move can be made.

However, the co-ordinates of the same chess piece are constantly being fed through so if the piece has no moves available, the same message keeps being displayed over and over again until a different button is pressed, and the same thing happens again if that piece has no moves.
How would I go about only printing the same message once each time a piece is clicked?

I tried using a do while loop where the condition in the while loop was only check if the button has moves available if the value of the co-ordinates are different to the ones being fed in. But this made no difference?

```
        while(!correctMove){
            do{
                fromXCo = s.getFromXInt();
                fromYCo = s.getFromYInt();
                toXCo = s.getToXInt();
                toYCo = s.getToYInt();

                    p = board.getPiece(fromXCo, fromYCo);

                    //checks if occupied co-ordinate, if not goes back out the loop and asks again.
                    if (!board.occupied(fromXCo, fromYCo)){
                        System.out.println("Please choose occupied co-ordinates \n");
                        correctMove = false;
                    }

                    //checks if the colour is the same as the player's. If not, asks for co-ordinates again.
                    if (p.getColour() != getPieces().getColour()){
                        System.out.println("Please move your own pieces \n");
                        correctMove = false;
                    }

                    //tells player their selected piece
                    System.out.println("Your selected piece is " + p.getChar());

                    //looks through available moves for piece
                    moves = p.availableMoves();

                    //if no moves available, asks for new co-ordinates.
                    if (moves == null){
                        System.out.println("No moves available for this piece \n");
                        correctMove = false;
                    }
                    else {

                        Move found = null;

                        for( Move m : moves){
                            //checks if move can be done
                            if (m.ToX() == toXCo && m.ToY() == toYCo){
                                //if move is allowed- exit loop
                                found = m; 

                                correctMove = true;

                            }
                        }

                        if (found == null) {
                            //if move can't be, ask for new co-ordinates
                            System.out.println("This move is not legal \n");
                            correctMove = false;

                        }   
                    }
                }while(fromXCo != s.getFromXInt() && fromYCo != s.getFromYInt() && toXCo != s.getToXInt() && toYCo != s.getToYInt());
            }
```

Comment: A perfect case where you can re-do some logic in your program, or you can use some sentinel variable that exits the "while" loop, or you can use a goto and get criticizes for even suggesting it.... in 3...2...1...

Comment: You can exit a while loop immediately with the break statement.

Comment: Both comments so far very important. I'd add that instead of adding code, try removing and/or combining code to get to your solution (or at least closer to it...)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the purpose of `while` is so if a legal piece with legal move is not selected user can repeat the selection. You won't need to have two `while` loops (the inner `while` seems to be acting just as an `if`). This is how I would go about it (pseudocode):

```
correctMove = false;
While(!correctMove) {
    square = inputNewSquare();
    if(isEmpty(square))
        "click on a piece"
    else if(pieceHasRightColor(square))
        "you can only move your own piece"
    else if(!pieceHasMove(square))
        "this piece has no legal move"
    else {
        //move(s) found, do stuff
        correctMove = true;
    }
}
```